# Простой IDE для JavaScript

Tags: jquery, ide, javascript

Followup к теме [Имеет ли смысл учить ребенка ООП](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/144983/c-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%BF)

Начать вбивать в голову оболтусу основы JavaScript'а, дело вроде движется.

Писать в нотепаде это конечно хорошо, но надо бы приучать к IDE и сразу же стал вопрос по-поводу выбора IDE. Я сам обычно для этих целей всегда использовал Eclipse, но тут как-то тяжеловато получается.

**Итак вопрос:** подскажите небольшой, простенький IDE для JavaScript'а, который бы подсвечивал синтаксис, подсказывал методы/функции и позволял на ходу просмотреть исполнение в встроенном браузере (ну или запускал внешний браузер). Если бы поддерживал jQuery вообще было бы супер.

**P.S.** Оболтусу 11 лет!

Comment: Только не нужно аболтуса сразу обучать жквери. Пусть он сначала познает ванильный жаваскрипт, .т.е., как реализовать то, для чего сейчас используют жквери на нативном жаваскрипте безо всяких библиотек

Comment: до jQuery я думаю дойдем не скоро...

Comment: Отказался от громоздких IDE в пользу блокнотика notepad++ :)

Comment: Я думаю не стоит сразу переходить к IDE, а вот редактор хороший посоветую - SublimeText 2

Comment: @andreycrane Вот частенько вижу упоминания SublimeText 2. Кто нибудь сможет объяснить, какие (с их точки зрения) у этого чуда преимущества перед vim?

Comment: Наверное вряд ли стоит их вообще сравнивать. Конечно vim гораздо более продвинут в своей настройке и кастомизируемости, но не всякая психика может такое переварить на начальных этапах знакомства с программированием)))

Comment: Вообще-то у vim'а ориентация на лёгкую (менее утомительную) и быструю работу. Если психике не приемлет такой ориентации, то ах.

Comment: Ну по крайней мере я в vim'е по своему опыту всегда совершал масу лишних телодвижений по сравнению  с Sublime

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#JavaScript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Мне бы отца программиста, пустил слезу :)*

При изучении **JavaScript** и **jQuery** тоже хотел себе найти хороший IDE и в результате напоролся на статейку [**клик**](http://web.archive.org/web/20130329232845/http://habrahabr.ru/qa/11301/), почитайте.

А вот собственно программа [Visual Web Developer 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ru-ru/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express)

Answer (score 7):

[JetBrains Webstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) - попробуйте, не разочаруетесь. Там много [возможностей](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/index.html) (особенно вкусный - это [Live Edit](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCVwdvufTds)), это, наверное, самая лучшая IDE для JavaScript.

Comment: он платный... и сильно навороченный. Надо бы что-то попроще

Comment: Тогда вопрос: что вы еще пробовали, чтобы сразу не предлагать? EAP версии у JetBrains бесплатны, кстати. А "лишними" функциями можно пока не пользоваться ;)

Comment: Пробовал Eclipse, Netbeans, Aptana. А что у WebStorm есть EAP версия?

Comment: Хм, раньше была. А сейчас действительно: EAP program is currently closed.

Comment: @Barmaley, если религия позволяет, то можно найти и [альтернативный вариант для скачивания](http://nnm-club.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=631577) ))

Comment: @Deonis, Или как говорит Попов: "Купите мои видео-обучения, а не качайте, чтоб совесть была чиста и Ваш проект приносил Вам прибыль" xD

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web. Он бесплатный и значительно превосходит по возможностям многие платные IDE. Если нужна поддержка jQuery или любой другой библиотеки, просто подключите исходники нужной библиотеки через reference path. Так же можно настроить автоматическое подключение нужного файла через настройки. В каждом проекте можно создавать папку Scripts и в ней _references.js - в этом файле уже подключаем нужные библиотеки и API через reference path. Они будут импортироваться в каждый открываемый js-файл, тем самым встроенная система intellisense будет распознавать объекты и пространства имен, объявленные во внешних файлах.

Answer (score 4):

Небольшой список редакторов, может подберете что-то )) 
**JSEclipse**
**SciTe** - простенький редактор
**Cloud9** - облачный редактор (на всякий случай)
**PSPad freeware editor** - простой бесплатный редактор
**Komodo IDE** - отличная среда разработки, но Вам надо полегче, поэтому рекомендую его облегченную версию **Komodo Edit**
**RJ TextED** - простой редактор, но хороший зараза, это по мне
Также наверное можно собрать свою IDE )) на базе FF и его расширений - дополнений

А вообще, конечно **WebStorm** рулит ))
На крайний случай **Sublime** с плагинами

Comment: +1 к SublimeText. Отличный текстовый редактор именно для ваших целей

Comment: посмотрю сегодня вечером на Sublime

Answer (score 1):

1. Komdo
2. Aptana
3. WebStorm

*остальные так-себе*

А вообще толку от ide в javascript мало. Особенно, если ребёнок знает основы. Лучше допихайте в ребёнка javascript, а потом показывайте **основы eclipse**, когда ребёнок будет изучать **основы java/c++**

p.s. Ответ написан 12-летним ребёнком, который сам изучил js, учит java, и юзает eclipse

p.p.s. А сейчас какой редактор он использует? Обычный блокнот или notepad++? Если первое, то срочно надо переучивать ко второму или сублайну

**UPDATE1** Помню я когда-то в свои давние 11 лет попробовал ide eclipse, зная только js. Я посчитал его набором ненужных штучек. А когда я начинал учить java, то пришлось снова к нему приучиватся. Сначала с огромной неохотой. Лишь  спустя 2 месяца я привык к eclipse и лишь спустя 4 полюбил его. Для ребёнка это долгий срок. **Так что лучше не отпугните ребёнка от eclipse сейчас, чтобы он сам привык к нему потом**